# Why would an empty delegate event handler cause a CA1061 warning?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

**Update:** This occurs when the Code Analysis option "Suppress results from generated code (managed only)" is turned off, and Rule Set is set to "Microsoft Basic Design Guideline Rules".

On 2013-04-26, Microsoft confirmed this is a bug, but will not fix it in either this or the next version of Visual Studio.

[Link to MS Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758403/certain-event-handlers-initialized-with-empty-delegates-triggering-ca1061-warning-in-code-analysis)

We frequently initialize event handlers with an empty delegate to avoid the need for checking nulls. E.g.:

```
public EventHandler SomeEvent = delegate {};
```

However, since starting to compile some of our code in Visual Studio 2012 (RTM), I'm noticing a lot of events in derived classes are now triggering [CA1601: Do not hide base class methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182143.aspx) warnings in Visual Studio 2012's Code Analysis.

Here's a sample that will trigger the warning:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

[assembly: CLSCompliant( true )]

namespace TestLibrary1
{
    public abstract class Class1
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate {};
    }

    public class Class2 : Class1
    {
        // this will cause a CA1061 warning
        public event EventHandler SelectionCancelled = delegate { };
    }

    public class Class3 : Class1
    {
        // this will not cause a CA1061 warning
        public event EventHandler SelectionCancelled;
    }
}
```

Note: In VS2012 the warning is triggered when compiled in either .NET 4.5 or .NET 4.0. The same sample does not trigger the warning in VS2010.

Performance reasons aside, **are there any legitimate reasons we shouldn't be initializing events with empty delegates?** The default assumption is that it's probably just a quirk in the analysis in Visual Studio 2012.

Here's the code analysis result for those that don't have access to VS2012 yet:

> CA1061 Do not hide base class methods Change or remove 'Class2.Class2()' because it hides a more specific base class method: 'Class1.Class1()'.   TestLibrary1    Class1.cs   14

**Addendum:** I found that the option to "Suppress results from generated code" in the code analysis is turned off.

Also, I found that this seems to occur when the event handler in the base type is both:

- a delegate other than EventHandler or EventHandler -and-
- events in both the base class and the derived class are initialized using an anonymous method or empty delegate (either inline or in the constructor).

Of possible relevance: We're running Visual Studio 2012 RTM, which was installed in-place over the release candidate.

Comment: Are you initializing your EventHandlers this way to avoid having to do null-checks on them before you fire them?

Comment: That's the predominant reason, yes.

Comment: It looks to me to be a quirk of VS 2012.  If you were overwriting a delegate in the base class, I could maybe see it, but as it stands, it doesn't appear to match the description of CA1061 at all: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182143.aspx

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it's complaining about your default constructor, as that would match the method signatures that are being displayed in the error, but I don't know why the one class causes it and the other doesn't.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on VS2012 with the code above. Are you sure the error refers to the event handler?

Comment: @Brian: can you try it with "Suppress results from generated code" turned off in code analysis? I had a coworker that couldn't reproduce it either until that option was unchecked.

Comment: @Sean: Same result. I pasted your code into a console app and the only warning I get is that Class3.SelectionCancelled is never used.

Comment: I repro.  Turning the option back on fixes it.  It is definitely a bug, constructors cannot hide each other.  You can file this at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Updated with code analysis settings and rule set and Connect link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the C# compiler generates a static delegate used to initialize your instance delegate, which is named the same for both Class1 and Class2.

`Class1.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1` exists for use by Class1's constructor to initialize `PropertyCancelled`, while `Class2.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1_` exists for use by Class2's constructor to initialize `SelectionCancelled`.

It's unfortunate that the C# compiler doesn't include some sort of record of the parent class' auto-generated 'stuff' when deciding how to name auto-generated 'stuff' for a child class.  Crack this open in ILDasm and the issue becomes immediately obvious.  Good to know that you found a work around.  The warning is completely reasonable to ignore, given that you can't touch the static delegates from C#, thanks to non-C#-compliant naming.

Comment: That's certainly a rational explanation for what is happening, but doesn't address why it has only started with the most recent version of Visual Studio. However, I've found a lot of other oddities in 2012's Code Analysis in the last week, all about anonymous methods related to event handlers and LINQ queries, so thanks for the insight.